# How do I remove the "Undo" popup when deleting a file in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, notification, delete

When I send a file to the Trash using the delete keyboard button, a popup appears at the top of the nautilus window, saying that the file has been removed, and showing a button to undo the operation.

I find this extremely annoying, because I can't click anything below that popup, and I have to wait until it disappears. Besides, I can undo the deletion with just a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, so I don't find it at all useful.

How can I get rid of this notification? I've looked in the preferences but there's nothing about this.

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and my GNOME version is 3.28.2.

Comment: This is a really annoying problem. I just couldn't understand why someone would put this "feature" in.

Answer (score 13):

I "removed" GTK notifications altogether, hoping there aren't any useful or important notifications.

1. Go to `~/.themes/THEME-IN-USE/gtk-3.0`
2. Open `gtk.css` and add this at the end:

   ```
   .app-notification { padding: 0; margin: -80px 0 0 0; opacity: 0;}
   ```

   and save.
3. *Refresh* theme in GNOME Tweaks (change to another one, and again change to your theme in use).

Now you can't see the popup.

Tested on *Nautilus 3.26.4, GNOME 3.30.1*.

Comment: Just a pointer, `~/.themes/` is one of the *possible* directories where your theme are. The theme currently in use can be in other locations, e.g. `/usr/share/themes/` (default location for pre-installed and system-wide installed themes), `~/.local/share/themes/`.

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu 20.4 (directory gtk-3.20).

Comment: On ubuntu 20.04. I don't see `~/.themes/`. In `/usr/share/themes`, there are many subdir, eg. `Ambiance`, `Yaru-light`, etc. So which one should I change?

Comment: On 20.04, the popup no longer showed, but it still blocked the mouse from clicking whatever would be underneath the popup. One time I actually clicked the invisible "undo" button and undeleted my file.

Answer (score 0):

Gnome 43 has the notification at the bottom instead of the top, which is an improvement for folders that have no content at the bottom.

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/2589

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1262016)