# How to disable Nautilus popup on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: nautilus, 20.04

On Ubuntu 20.04, Nautilus shows pop-ups when a copy is finished, or when a file is deleted ("undo"). However, the pop-ups are annoying because they cover the files underneath for quite a while.

1. How to disable all the pop-ups completely?
2. How to selectively disable only the "undo" pop-up, keeping the other pop-ups active?

I tried to follow this procedure (for Ubuntu 18.04), 
[How to remove the "Undo" popup when deleting a file in Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073453/how-to-remove-the-undo-popup-when-deleting-a-file-in-nautilus)
but in Ubuntu 20.04 the `~/.themes` folder does not exist.

Comment: `~/.themes/` is one of the possible folders where your theme are. Check other ones, e.g. `/usr/share/themes/`, `~/.local/share/themes/`.

Answer (score 4):

1. Checked in `/usr/share/themes/`;
2. Found Yaru-dark (theme currently in use, double checked on GNOME Tweaks);
3. Opened in folder in Terminal (right click on the folder);
4. Ran

   ```
   sudo gedit gtk.css
   ```
5. added the line

   ```
   .app-notification { padding: 0; margin: -80px 0 0 0; opacity: 0;}
   ```

   at the end
6. Saved file, closed, refreshed the theme by using GNOME Tweaks;

Now all pop-ups are off.

Comment: This is temporary solution as files in `/usr/share/themes` may be overwritten on next package update. Consider to use local copy in `~/.themes/` or `~/.local/share/themes/` as pomsky suggests.

Comment: In a slightly unrelated note, it's a bad practice to [run GUI applications with `sudo`](https://askubuntu.com/q/270006/480481), at least use the `-H` flag.