# Disable "undo" notification in GNOME Files (Nautilus)

Tags: gnome, files, notification

When deleting files there is always a small popup with undo in GNOME Files (Nautilus), which overlays other files and is pretty disturbing.
How can I disable the notification within the application?

Comment: have you tried from system settings page? https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLcYX.png

Comment: Yes, it's "off" all the way. https://imgur.com/a/T4miyTj
These are system wide notifications.

 I mean inside the Files window. Like https://imgur.com/Ri8m6Fz

Comment: Ohhhh, this is nautilus? -.-
Unfortunately there is no .themes folder in ~

Comment: Regarding the `.themes` folder, [pomsky's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073453/how-do-i-remove-the-undo-popup-when-deleting-a-file-in-nautilus#comment2095583_1102984) may help.

Comment: Unforunately it didn't work.